# Get parameters of a function within function that has a dynamic generic

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to drill into a param from => second param of a function that is an object => from the object I want to get the "onSuccess" function (its optional, but it will be required when I ask for it) => get the first param of the function that is dynamic.

The `Parameters<NonNullable<Parameters<typeof sampleFunction>[1]["onSuccess"]>>[0]` works, but I don't want to use it everywhere as it's not very readable. I want to make something dynamic such as: `ResponseOf<typeof sampleFunction>`

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&ssl=46&ssc=57&pln=46&pc=44#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgGE4BtcBGiA1gDwAqyAvMnCAJ4B8yA3gLABQyyA9iAMoBXBEgDOogPwAuZAAooEUej6iIM8gBpkACwhwAJtEky69AJTVmANx7B9Abk7c+AMTjBcghdLnQoPKBlBEGIQHgB3EAsqa1sHJ2RcOAIIXBlRMChQAHNHLmQAegLkADoynjBdKE4AX05OUEhYRBQMYFQEMGA+AAU4elweAwpqWgZmCAAPSBB9UTRMHHwiBDJyZnZ8rzTkDKyQXISi0rLeSuha+o5G6HgkBfbO7pARmlMNhLB6dDVkACJUD0AJJ-PLcdD9QYGGRtDpdXqQob6CiMPJ1DicGDBJ58WiYOHPV5jJiyTbcbajP5-DQJJIpXCU6kJMoldD+dCiWow-E4kB9AZIlFmbmPeEvdasBIKMBeECS-LcL4-GQA4FMhXICEC6Hy7h65DbGka7h01JG-XcFlsngchLcdH2y4YjgIFRgXZwAC26FwEBc2LFo1kAH0IVAvQBGEwMLQIPCEEiiEVLBOrUgsZD6OBgODR+gAbQAusgaoxhQ8CbiYrrkNLZXjRc9SXaDVAdn9sjweNlfSVXZ71fqWXHlomEjUzE7OEqUAARRTABT6AByfFn9BAXuACHI3xQND64c9ECaolIq5Ay8E+GSvtIh69J6MpBnPBgHu9vv9IF5jHzEcLfM-j4IQREUUQ-kLRg-wABkLPIrimZQoHdGdkAAJUUZQQFUAB5GBSASSgphmOY5BbGBFwyPNzT1VRXVmGQMxA4QxGMORJjzaJmFMexEmSVJ0kyHJ7HzYghP2bJCzzEtaMtMo4CgbIk2JIsEm44lmBoYjpggWZ5lkSioGo4ktHovh9CY3gBFY8CfFkTjkFAGBoGQABVDTeLEiScmk4lZJOEpFOUvMi08hgEgkdzkBkEAICsaAEOdND51ERcIH0XcflGTClBUCB8JfPc3w-H0-QDZ5UU4IA)

```
interface ApiCallback<T = any> {
  onSuccess?: (response: T, headers?: any) => void;
  onFailure?: (error: unknown) => void;
  label: string;
  // ...other
}

interface ApiActionPayload<T = any> extends ApiCallback<T> {
  url: string;
  // ... other
}

interface ApiAction<T = any> {
  type: "API";
  payload: ApiActionPayload<T>;
}

function apiAction<T = any>({
  url = "",
  label = "",
  ...props
}: ApiActionPayload<T>): ApiAction<T> {
  return {
    type: "API",
    payload: {
      url,
      label,
      ...props
    }
  }
}

const sampleFunction = (_param1: any, callbacks: ApiCallback<{ data: any[] }>): ApiAction => {
  return apiAction({
    url: "google.com",
    ...callbacks
  })
}

type DesiredNonDynamicType = Parameters<NonNullable<Parameters<typeof sampleFunction>[1]["onSuccess"]>>[0];


export type ResponseOf<
  T extends (
    first: any,
    second: { onSuccess?: (x: any) => any; label: string;[k: string]: any },
    ...args: any[]
  ) => any> = T extends (first: any, second: { onSuccess?: (x: infer U) => any;[k: string]: any }, ...args: any[]) => any
  ? U : never;


type DesiredType = ResponseOf<typeof sampleFunction>;
```

One of things I've tried, e.g.:

```
export type ResponseOf<
  T extends (
    first: any,
    second: { onSuccess?: (x: any) => any; label: string; [k: string]: any },
    ...args: any[]
  ) => any
= T extends (first: any, second: { onSuccess?: (x: infer U) => any; [k: string]: any }, ...args: any[]) => any
  ? U
  : never;
```

Comment: The "thing you tried" [works](https://tsplay.dev/N78oqm) (except for a little typo).  What, specifically, is the problem with it?

Comment: Ah, the issue is; this evaluated as `never` for me. I have updated the the Playground link, with a more real life scenario. (I have added a required "label" field)

Comment: Oh, you're hitting a contravariance issue.  Instead of trying to work through that, could you just use `ApiCallback` in your definition like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMLBlN) shows? If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you, should we no problem - it seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this is to re-use your `ApiCallback` utility type in your [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  Writing `ApiCallback<infer U>` is going to be much more straightforward than trying to reverse-engineer anything.  For example:

```
export type ResponseOf<T> =
  T extends (first: any, second: ApiCallback<infer U>, ...args: any) => any ? U : never
```

That gives you the behavior you desired:

```
type DesiredType = ResponseOf<typeof sampleFunction>;
/* type DesiredType = {
    data: any[];
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgGE4BtcBGiA1gDwAqyAvMnCAJ4B8yA3gFDLID2IAygK4IkAZ2EB+AFzIAFFAjD0PYRCnkANMgAWEOABNo4qXXoBKaswBuXYLoDcHbiABicYLn5zJM6FC5Qp-CDEIFwA7iBmVJbWdg64cAQQuFLCYFCgAOb2nAD0OcgAdEVcYNpQbAC+bGygkLCIKBjAqAhgwDwACnD0uFx6FNS0DMwQAB6QILrCaJg4+EQIZOTM7Jweycip6SBZDnmFRdyl0JXVtdDwSDPNre0gAzTGKw5g9OgqyABEqB0Akp-ZZDobq9PRSJotNqdEF9XQURj2KpsGCBW48WiYSF3B5DJjSVbIdaDT6fNRxBJJYmkhxFAroXzoYSVcGYtEgLo9WHwkwsm5Q+7LVgOORgDwgIWcTivd5Sb5-amSoEwsESxWEqC4Mlq5DxRKahyK2n0riMg3IKqcKpIhBKMCbOAAW3QuAgTlR-MG0gA+sCoI6AIxGBgaBB4QgkYS8ubhxakFjIXRwMBwIP0ADaAF1zYwedcseioqqRWKMXy7vizetZRkuFwMi6CjaHQrJbTQ-MIw4KiZTmxpSgACLyYByXQAOR4A-oIEdwAQ5DeKBoXT9DogdWEpAnIDH-HwCRdpBXjvXBlI-a4MHtTpdbpAbMYaf9GbTnx4AiE8mEnwzjEfAAYM3saoxkUKA7X7ZAACV5EUEBlAAeRgeFqAcSgxgmKYZBgEdUlTDRlBtSYozDBYyFAGBoGQABVRgNFpOAoAySNcUiZhjGQMQaOQKQQAgCwTj7RdkCHYQRwgXQF3eQYYIUJQICQ89F0va9nVdd07gRNgcgAKmQSDRPEyThJoAlOETZNU0zRFkB0nIgA)